# what are the parameters will pass throug by .config() and .run() in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I only see .config with passing $routeProvider, what else will passing through by .config and also want to know what are the parameters will pass through by .run in angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are dependency injected services.

So for `config` you should be asking for `constant` or `provider`. For `run` you should be asking for `service`, `factory`, `value`, `constant`.

You should notice i'm saying *should be asking for*, because we're dependency injecting the services, the function parameters are effectively asking angular DI for particular instances. If angular has one it will supply the function arg with that instance, similar to a `fn.call({}, someDep)`

So for example:

```
angular.module('myMod', [])
   .provider('myFactory', myFactoryProvider)
   .factory('anotherService', anotherServiceFactory)
   .config(function (myFactoryProvider) {

   })
   .run(function (myFactory, anotherService) {
       /** myFactory is the service that was setup
         * by the config myFactoryProvider
         */
   });
```

I've left out the implementations for `myFactoryProvider` and `anotherServiceFactory` so you look up angular docs to see what they're about.

The `config` and `run` describe the phases of an angular application. `config` phase is for setting up services and pipelines like the `$http` request pipeline and generally pre-app configuration.

The `run` phase is for when the app has loaded and you want to do something like load some user information from the api or anything else post-app load.

I personally used to use the config all the time with `$stateProvider` and things. But, I rarely used the `run` function.